# Workflow task - email link to edit page rather to display page in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, sharepint

I am looking for the way for the workflow task email to contain a link directly to "Edit task" page rather than "Display task", so user doesnt have to click "Edit" button but go directly from the email to a page with "Approve/Reject" buttons.

I noticed that the task link that emailed to a user does contain task ID (which can be used to make a link to "edit task" page) but its not available in task values in "Assign a task" workflow action in Sharepoint designer.

Any ideas how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, there is no simple way to do this.

One thing you can do is to create Workflows that set the Task outcome to "Approved" or "Rejected" or what have you, and then link that to a Custom Action defined on the list Display form. Then you get a "one click" solution to updating the form- *however* the custom action buttons appear in the Ribbon by default and can't easily be moved into the form itself.

Another thing you can do is create a custom task form that includes buttons that activate a JavaScript function that either initiates the above workflows or updates the task itself through CSOM.

I have tried both of the above but neither is ideal because manually initiating workflows require elevated permissions on the list item.

The below solution seems like the simplest, even though it is "not smart". Essentially you create a custom Display Form for the Task list that immediately redirects to the Edit form of the same list.

[Automatically open SharePoint 2013 workflow tasks in Edit mode for easy one-click approvals](https://sharepointlibrarian.com/2018/07/18/automatically-open-sharepoint-2013-workflow-tasks-in-edit-mode-for-easy-one-click-approvals/)

Answer (score -1):

Theres actually a quite easy way to do it. Under "Workflow context" (When pressing the Fx button) you have the option to choose "Current item url". Put that value into a variable and then add a replace variable replacing "dispform.aspx" with "editform.aspx". It does require 2013 workflows to use the replace action though :)

Comment: Not Sure what you mean. I want to include link to "task edit" in the body of the email which is sent when task created. How can I put a variable and than add a replace variable?

Comment: Uhm that's like a very basic thing to do in a workflow. I assumeed you was familiar with SharePoint designer workflows, but that isn't tha case?

Comment: I thought I would need to create an action to do that, but where do I do that if task created and email sent in one go? Its a TASK I need a link to edit page, not a hole workflow.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint designer or not for your workflow?

Comment: Yes, I am using SharePoint designer

Comment: Ok then first Set a variable called "LinkToTask" - the content of it should be "Current item url" found under "Workflow context". Then add a replace action replacing "dispform.aspx" with "editform.aspx". Finally use the variable in the mail.

Comment: " I thought I would need to create an action to do that, but where do I do that if task created and email sent in one go? " - Where do I stick that replace action?

Comment: Open the workflow in SPD and add it where appropriate. I'm sorry but I don't know how to explain it any more if you all ready are using SPD and have entered the workflow...

Comment: Morten K it sounds like you are confusing the "Current Item" with the corresponding Task List item. They are not the same thing and your solution does not work for this situation.